No available connections in WSL2 + Ubuntu + KDE
I use:

Windows 10 Pro (ver. 22H2 19045.4529)
WSL2 (wsl --set-default-version 2)
Ubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma 5.24.7 (sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop)
Kernel 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform X11
X-server: VcXsrv
static IP address

I can "ping google.com" in Windows Terminal running Ubuntu and my connection works fine, no packets are lost.
I can do the same thing in the KDE terminal emulator and there is also a connection.
However, in KDE, in the Networks tab, I see the message "No available connections"
When trying to open the browser in KDE I also have no connection. KDE's built-in app store doesn't work either.
I used "sudo apt-get install network-manager":
network-manager is already the newest version (1.36.6-0ubuntu2)
There are already similar questions on stackoverflow, but they deal with the case when there is no connection at all in WSL, but I have it, but only in the terminal.
I'm new to WSL and new to networking, maybe I'm missing something important
